# Lapack version on Mac LION

Tags: macos, osx-lion, lapack, blas, accelerate-framework

Lapack 3.2.1 is not fully theard safe right...but 3.3 is which is recently being released by netlib with help of intel.

So do some one know whether or not Lapack 3.3 version would be shipped with new MacPro.

Answer (score 3):

The LAPACK version is right there in the header:

```
Definitions and prototypes for LAPACK v3.2.1 as provided Apple Computer.
```

More specifically, it's a modified version of [clapack](http://www.netlib.org/clapack/)-3.2.1, which has had some of the commonly used routines (things like LU factor and solve, Cholesky decomposition, etc) replaced with hand-tuned implementations.

**Edit:** Please note that I said it is a *modified* LAPACK-3.2.1.  In particular, among other modifications, the routines `slamch` and `dlamch` have been modified to make them both thread-safe and reentrant.  If you encounter any routines that are not thread-safe, that is a serious bug that you should [report](http://developer.apple.com/bugreporter/).